# How to plot a DataFrame with binary values as a color matrix?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that resembles the following:

```
Name V1 V2 V3
A    1  0  0
B    1  0  1
C    1  1  0
```

etc.

I would like to visualize it as a 2-d matrix with labeled rows and columns and with cells colored based on whether the value is 1 or 0.

In other words, I would like to do something like this: [Conditional coloring of a binary data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45173448/conditional-coloring-of-a-binary-data-frame-in-r)

but in Python.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can go check heatmap from seaborn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fleshing out Wen's comment into an answer - use `seaborn.heatmap`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()

df = df.set_index('Name')
df

      V1  V2  V3
Name            
A      1   0   0
B      1   0   1
C      1   1   0
```

```
sns.heatmap(df)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @cs96: Great, how to change the color legend tick labels? I want to display simply 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

Could plot them as an image with various cmap alternatives: https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html

But from here you would need more formatting...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(df.values, interpolation="nearest", cmap='Blues')
plt.show()
```

[image]